# message undefined offset 0 no codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, aplicação-web

Galera estou com um probleminha para setar os dados em uma view com o framework CodeIgniter.

**Model:**

```
// Metodo que busca os dados de um cliente especifico
public function getCliente($id){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from($this->table);
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $this->db->where($this->primaryKey, $id);
    return $this->db->get()->result_array()[0];
}
```

**Controller:**

```
// Verifica se o id é nulo
if ($id != null){
   // Decodifica o id passado
   $id = decode($id);
   // Busca os dados do cliente especifico
   $data['cliente'] = $this->Clientes_model->getCliente($id);
} else {
  // Não busca dados
  $data['cliente'] = null;
}
```

**View:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nome *</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" class="form-control" required name="nome_cliente" value="<?php echo $cliente['nome_cliente']; ?>">
    </div>
</div>
```

mas estou retornando o erro:

> message undefined offset 0

já dei um `var_dump` e existe essa posição no `array`, não sei o porque desse erro?

Comment: Talvez o erro não seja ai! em qual linha dá o erro? e faça a leitura no sua view para ver aonde o erro para!

Comment: o erro esta nessa linha: return $this->db->get()->result_array()[0];

o erro não para, fica sempre gerando novo erro até travar o navegador

Comment: nessa linha faça `return $this->db->row_array();` (https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html) ele vai retornar uma linha somente, e é isso que precisa! e verifique se depois dessa linha está retornando algo.

Comment: consegui exibir, agora ele fica repetindo a view, enquanto seta o value dos campos

Comment: É algo que você está fazendo... !!! leia o manual do CodeIgniter é simples http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/